# C# do not receive process MainWindowHandle

Tags: c#

I'm using the following code :

```
        if (!running()) // make sure osk is not running
            _process = Process.Start(@"c:\windows\system32\osk.exe");

        for (int bailout = 0; bailout < 50; bailout++)
        {
            if (_process.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            _process.Refresh();
        }
```

It seems to work on most computers but not all..

(I already tried to increase 'bailout' and the sleep time).

I exit the loop without receiving `MainWindowHandle`.

Comment: Have you read through the various exceptions for when MainWindowHandle might be IntPtr.Zero in the docs? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle.aspx

Comment: This is the kind of "solution" that would make me ponder whether I'm doing something wrong - you're launching the on screen keyboard. Why do you then *need* it's window handle?

Comment: A better solution may be to p/Invoke EnumWindows() and find the window that way. Then just use the GetWindowText() method to read the title bars and match against "On-Screen Keyboard". This example will show you all the necessary pieces in the sample at the bottom: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumwindows

Comment: Oh, I also noticed that if it's already running, you'll get an exception, since _process will be null and you'll get a NullReference exception in your if statement and in the _process.Refresh() call.